# Google Visualization Query - Abort Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-visualization, google-query-language

I am working on an interface that contains several high-intensity SQL queries, then renders multiple Google charts which are currently being called via AJAX using the google.visualization.Query object:

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query('/report.ashx');
query.send(callbackMethod);
//....
function callbackMethod(rs){
    var data = rs.getDataTable();
    var graph = new google.visualization.AreaChart(target_div);
    graph.draw(data);
}
```

As the interface can be filtered dynamically I have encountered a scenario whereby a query can be running, whilst the user could potentially choose to re-filter and hence re-query the data source. If the first query is still running and the second query begins and returns before the first query then the chart will be drawn just fine. However, when the first query finally completes it could completely overwrite the chart with the old data, ignoring the current filters.

I have read that there is the ability to pass a jQuery AJAX object in, which exposes an XHR object allowing me to call .abort() on the XHR which would cancel the request (albeit this would still process on the server, but that's a hit I'm willing to take). Unfortunately I can find no examples of this and the Google documentation is less than helpful in this respect. Has anybody encountered the same, and if so - have they solved the problem?

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: or pass the request timestamp to `onSuccess`, and not update the chart if data is outdated?

Comment: "report.ashx" is returning data in the format: 

google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"22"...

So not sure how I could compare timestamps against this.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `callbackMethod` in a higher order function to keep track of the request time, and use `query.send(callback())` instead of `query.send(callbackMethod)`.

```
var mostRecentReqTime;
var callback = function() {
  var reqTime = Date();
  return function() {
    if (reqTime < mostRecentReqTime) return;
    var data = rs.getDataTable();
    var graph = new google.visualization.AreaChart(target_div);
    graph.draw(data);
    mostRecentReqTime = reqTime;
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Fabricator, I will bear this in mind however I am really after a solution which would allow the request to be aborted altogether.